# Auto adding html table row when new user is added in database, is this possible?

Tags: php, html, pdo

Need help!
I want this every time a new user added in the database it will automatically add a new html table row with its data.

My code looks like this:

```
 <div class="col" id="viewTeacher" style="display:none;" >
            <h1 style="text-align:center">View Teacher</h1>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ID NUMBER</th>
                    <th scope="col">NAME</th>
                    <th scope="col">CONTACT</th>
                    <th scope="col">ADDRESS</th>
                    <th scope="col">EMAIL</th>
                   
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php while ($row = $q->fetch(1)): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row[1]) ?></th>
                        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['2']) ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['3']) ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['4']) ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['5']) ?></td>
                        <td><a href="deleteProcess.php?id=<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><img src="../icons/delete.svg"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <tr>
                    <?php while ($row = $q->fetch(2)): ?>
                    <th scope="row"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row[1]) ?></th>
                        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['2']) ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['3']) ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['4']) ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['5']) ?></td>
                        <td><a href="deleteProcess.php?id=<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><img src="../icons/delete.svg"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

As you can see, I manually added every table with the while loop for it to add in the table.

Many thanks!

Comment: Use [fetch_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) and loop through that array or do a while on `$q->fetch()`

Comment: How should I display all the values in the table without creating manually the table?